# TTransportException Exception while working with Apache Thrift

Tags: java, sockets, thrift, transport

I am working with apache Thrift. I am getting TTransportException exception while everthing looks fine with my code. Here is my Thrift Server Code:

```
private TNonblockingServerSocket socket;
/**
 * @breif Store processor instance.
 */
private PringService.Processor processor;
/**
 * Store server instance.
 */
private TServer tServer;
/**
 *
 * @breif A handle to the unique Singleton instance.
 */
static private ThriftServer _instance = null;

/**
 * @breif The unique instance of this class.
 * @throws TTransportException
 */
static public ThriftServer getInstance() throws TTransportException {
    if (null == _instance) {
        _instance = new ThriftServer();
    }
    return _instance;
}

/**
 * @breif A Ctor for ThriftServer. Initialize all members.
 * @throws TTransportException
 */
private ThriftServer() throws TTransportException {
    socket = new TNonblockingServerSocket(Config.THRIFT_PORT);
    processor = new PringService.Processor(new Handler());
    THsHaServer.Args args = new THsHaServer.Args(socket);
    args.processor(processor);
    args.transportFactory(new TFramedTransport.Factory());
    args.inputProtocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());
    args.outputProtocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());
    tServer = new THsHaServer(args);
    /*tServer = new THsHaServer(processor, socket,
     new TFramedTransport.Factory(),
     new TFramedTransport.Factory(),
     new TBinaryProtocol.Factory(),
     new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());*/
}

/**
 * @breif main method
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws TTransportException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws TTransportException {
    // To Run it directly from PringCore.jar, else use SmsProcessor Helper functionality
    ThriftServer server = new ThriftServer();
    server.execute(args);
}

@Override
/**
 * @breif Starts the execution.
 */
protected void execute(String[] args) {
    if (db != null) {
        db.close();
    }
    tServer.serve();
}
```

private static class Handler implements PringService.Iface {
......
}
}

And This is my thrift client:

```
    TTransport transport;
  try {
     transport = new TSocket("localhost", Config.THRIFT_PORT);        
     transport.open();

     TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
     PringService.Client client = new PringService.Client(protocol);

     String result = client.importPringer(2558456, true);

    System.out.println("Result String is ::"+result);
     transport.close();
  } catch (TTransportException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (TException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

When I run my Thrift server and then run thrift client, I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
```

Am I using mis-matching transport sockt/layer on my thrift server or client ? Or there is something other wrong?

Thanks in Advance for your guidance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `TNonblockingServerSocket`, you need to use `TFramedTransport` both server- and client-side. The [documentation](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/server/TNonblockingServer.java;h=10a8eba799dc3e17cea43c7c44dfff8b9a40b915;hb=HEAD#l38) of `TNonblockingServerSocket` is quite explicit about that:

> To use this server, you MUST use a TFramedTransport at the outermost transport, otherwise this server will be unable to determine when a whole method call has been read off the wire. Clients must also use TFramedTransport.

Your client should therefore look like this:

```
TTransport transport;

try {
    transport = new TSocket("localhost", Config.THRIFT_PORT);        
    transport.open();

    TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(new TFramedTransport(transport));
    PringService.Client client = new PringService.Client(protocol);

    String result = client.importPringer(2558456, true);

    System.out.println("Result String is ::"+result);
    transport.close();
} catch (TTransportException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```